# find and replace string but replace strings in executable files and binary files

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script which finds all the ascii text characters and replaces a string only in ascii text files and it should not replace the strings in all the binary files and executable files.

i have tried this:

```
 find .  -type f \! -executable \! \( -name "*.o" -name "*.class"  \) -print -exec sed -i 's/\<hello\>/Hello/g' '{}' \;
```

I imagine that there could be more and more binary files and writing them using -name may not be correct...

if anybody could help me and it should not be a one line script which i wrote.

Comment: What version of `find` do you have that has an `-executable` test? Most versions I've ever seen before would refuse to run due to bad options there...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the file command to check the type:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read filename; do
    file "$filename" | grep -q "ASCII text" || continue
    echo "Updating $filename"
    sed -i 's/\<hello\>/Hello/g' "$filename"
done < <(find . -type f \! -executable)
```